# Using XML Parser to get recent youtube videos from a user

Tags: javascript, xml, api, parsing, youtube

Yo!

So, my goal is to get the three most recent videos uploaded by a youtube user, in this case "aosjeff". I understand that I can send a "get" request to youtube and then parse that xml document using the XML parser (I cannot use php, the site-building site I'm using won't let me), and I'm attempting to use some code here to store the results of the "get" request in a string in javascript so that I can parse them. But whenever I run this code and call "alert(txt)", only the string "[object document]" is returned, and not the xml data. Here's the code:

```
function getVideoHTML()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/aosjeff/uploads",false);
    xmlhttp.send();

    txt = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    if (window.DOMParser)
    {
        parser=new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
    }
    else // Internet Explorer
    {
        xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async=false;
        xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
    }

    //document.getElementById("to").innerHTML=
    //xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    //document.getElementById("from").innerHTML=
    //xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("from")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    //document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=
    //xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    alert(txt);
}
```

That's one problem. The other, I guess, is how to use the parser--which I've read about but still don't understand. Can you all explain how it works? I understand that I search for a certain tag--and that then it gives me a list of the elements in that tag. But how do I navigate that list?

Cheers, thanks for your time

Simon

Comment: Anybody know anything about this? I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to parse the `responseXML` property using a DOMParser, because it's already a XML object. Use the string-to-xml parsing methods (recommended), or replace the `responseXML` property with `responseText`.

```
txt = xmlhttp.responseXML; // <-- This is a XML document object

if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml"); // <--- txt should be a string
} else {....}
```

should be:

```
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```